Which graduated sites use "Full" requirements and which ones use the "Beta" requirements?
Stack Exchange sites (with a few minor deviations), can have either "Private Beta", "Beta", or "Full" reputation requirements for privileges. I know that currently, only CS50 uses the Private Beta requirements, and that all of the Public Beta sites (and GenAI) use the Beta requirements, but what about the Graduated sites? Which ones use "Full" requirements and which ones use the "Beta" requirements?

May I suggest making any answer a community wiki as the answer is likely to change over time.

@W.O. No it's actually not. SE has stated that they aren't adding more sites to the "Full" list except in "exceptional circumstances", and Area51 proposals were already few and far between, and now (at least for me) Area51 is completely broken.

This is answered in part of How long until graduated sites get a new site design and increased privileges threshold?
